# Syncing On Prem SQL Server with Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database

We have a SQL 2016 instance running production systems at a pretty healthy load within AWS. On top of this we host instances of production databases in Azure for PowerBI and analysis usage.

At present the database is manually handled to be moved in to Azure on a schedule but we would love to have this either synced or automated. We have determined Log Shipping cannot work but are looking for an alternative which is secure and stable.

We have also looked at SQL Data Sync but are struggling to ensure security and encryption between clouds.

In terms of the databases they are about 10gb in size so not small but not huge.

Comment: What was your reasoning behind ruling out log shipping, as a matter of interest?